# Moderation tools "30d 14d 7d 2d" buttons do nothing

Tags: support, 10k-tools

On a tools page such as https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=today there are filter buttons across the top right:

```
30d 14d 7d 2d today
```

Clicking one of these buttons does nothing. It appears to go to a different page, but the list of posts shown under every heading remains the same. Is this a bug? What's the point of these buttons?

(My real reason for asking is that I was hoping to find questions closed over two days ago, so as to consider whether any of these might be candidates for deletion.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, only the questions under the "Most" categories ever really have the chance of changing. All of the "recent" categories are completely irrelevant to those modifiers, at least on Stack Overflow, because the list for today is usually too large to matter. If the list of Recent Votes, for example, only had three items on it for today, then changing to the last 2 days would display a larger list (even though today's would still be listed at the top).

So yes, it *is* functioning properly. The results between each time frame just don't differ that much, at least not at the moment. I can verify that the lists under Most Close Votes are different between the month and today timeframes. It's likely much more noticeable on smaller sites.